# How to handle closing a python kivy application through the menu of active Android applications

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy

I have a python kivy application for android and I need to close it correctly by doing something before that. I already found several answers on how to close the application correctly through the button, but did not find the answer how to do this through the application menu as in the picture
[image]

I tried to add my function or code after that
`if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()`

But this did not work, and here is the last thing I see in the logcat:

```
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

It works on PC, but how can I handle closing on android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't get to run any code when the app is closed this way. Instead, whenever your app is paused (or directly stopped) you should assume it will never be opened again. That means e.g. do whatever data storage you want in the `on_pause` method of your app class, because even though it's 'only' pausing it might be halted later by the user or by Android itself.

Comment: It really works, I added the on_pause method, and every time I hide the application, it goes to the code after the MyApp().run(). But at the same time, the application loses the ability to minimize and work in the background, as it does without the on_pause method. Maybe there is some kind of signal sent by Android when deleting the application from the list by means of a finger movement, which can be processed at the Java level?